# How to duplicate an old document with new date (flutter firestore)?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hello I try to duplicate an old document with new date.

I have a structure like this

```
Collection    document   subcollection    document       data
   name         date         id             idX       keys/values
```

Here is an example

```
    Collection    document   subcollection    document       data
  mycollection   2021/06/28       id1           id2         vote:1  
                                                id3         vote:1  
                                                id4         vote:1 

  mycollection   2021/06/29       id2           id4         vote:1  
                                                id5         vote:1
```

I try to duplication the last date 2021/06/29 with new current date 2021/06/30

like this

```
 mycollection   2021/06/30       id2           id4         vote:1  
                                               id5         vote:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the `doc` you want to duplicate and save it under the new path like here:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('col1').doc('2021/06/28').collection('subcollection').get().then((QuerySnapshot  querySnapshot){

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('col1').doc('2021/06/30').collection('subcollection').doc(doc.id).set(doc.data());
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I have lot of unknow idx, I can’t just get all from col1 and last date to set col 1 and. New date ? Or how can I iterate to automate the duplication ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. It duplicates not a whole subcollection.